# Laravel Custom Facade New Instance

Tags: laravel, ioc-container, laravel-5.3

Working on my first laravel package and running into trouble with how my Facade works, currently my use looks something like this:

```
{!! Custom::showValue() !}} //returns "default"

{!! Custom::setValue('test')->showValue() !}} //returns "test"

{!! Custom::showValue() !}} //returns "test"
```

I would expect the last element to go be a new class instance, as I've used bind instead of singleton when setting up my service provider:

```
public function register()
    {
        $this->registerCustom();
    }

public function registerCustom(){
    $this->app->bind('custom',function() {
        return new Custom();
    });
}
```

Is there something else I need to do to make it so every facade call to "Custom" returns a new class instance?

Comment: That's not how Laravel's Facades work. Facades are syntactic sugar that allows you to access a single instance's public methods through static access. Consider exposing a public factory method on the underlying class (or better yet, an actual Factory class), or use Dependency Injection to achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @maiorano84 mentioned you can not do this with `Facades` out of the box.

To answer your question, to make your `Custom` facade return a new instance you could add the following method to it:

```
/**
 * Resolve a new instance for the facade
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function refresh()
{
    static::clearResolvedInstance(static::getFacadeAccessor());

    return static::getFacadeRoot();
}
```

Then you could call:

```
Custom::refresh()->showValue();
```

(Obviously, you can call `refresh` something else if you want to)

One alternative to this would be to use the `app()` global function that comes with Laravel to resolve a new instance i.e.

```
app('custom')->showValue();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Ross, since my class deals with URLs, I ended up doing the same thing with always starting with the url() method which starts by just making a new $class = new static; and then running from that. getFacadeRoot looks like a better alternative though

Answer (score 2):

From laravel 9 you can use the `$cached = false` property inside your facade so it does not get cached:

```php
class YourFacade extends Facade
{

    protected static $cached = false;

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return ...;
    }

}
```